# Controlling dynamically added fields' tabbing order with Prototype

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

I'm creating various input fields dynamically using prototype js. Everything looks nice and cool and the fields are appended properly in the right place.

The only problem is that the field's tabbing order is messed up ...

When inside a textfield pressing tab doesn't switch focus to the field immediately below it. 
Instead it gives focus to inputs that existed before the new fields were dynamically added ...

Is there a clean and simple way to reset the field's tabbing order to the regular one, i.e. the one that would switch to the field immediately after in the DOM .

Note : this annoyance occured on Firefox 5.0. I didn't test it on other browsers yet.

Comment: You could manually set the taborder

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set the tab index. The issue here is that the *logical* order of fields any given HTML does not always match the *visual* order of those fields in the browser. So writing a script to automate this may not always work.

Comment: I'm sure this would work but I'll have to cheat a little since I don't know at generation time which fields will be present or not ...

Answer (score 0):

According to [W3C forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.11.1),

> Those elements that assign a positive value to [tabindex] are navigated first
>   ... Elements that have identical tabindex values should be navigated in the order they appear in the character stream.

So give all the dynamic fields the same value of 1 and they will be tabbed before any other field (which have an equivalent value of 0) in the order they are added to the document.

Comment: That is unfortunate. Perhaps the browser isn't following W3C specs, perhaps dynamically added fields are always exempt. I'll be interested to know if ascending index values do work, remember they don't have to be contiguous.